# after pi bullseye update deconz conbee 2 (zigbee usb gateway) not connected

Tags: raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

ConBee II (zigbee usb gateway)

- Deconz failure after Pi Bullseye update  June 16 2023
- the conbee II gateway no longer was reachable in deconz app and phoscon app
- the deconz app no longer shows the conbee2 device
- the phoscon app shows that the usb gateway is not connected

how do i get the deconz conbee 2 to show up again?

Answer (score 0):

here is what i learned while working on this bug

ConBee II - Deconz failure after Pi Bullseye update June 16 2023

```
the conbee II gateway no longer was reachable in deconz app and phoscon app
see: https://github.com/dresden-elektronik/deconz-rest-plugin/issues/6937
```

Summary of workaround

```
need to add a --dev=/dev/ttyACM0 to the deconz startup

cmd line example: '/usr/bin/deCONZ --http-port=8008' --dev=/dev/ttyACM0

deconz.service example: ExecStart=/usr/bin/deCONZ -platform minimal --http-port=8008 --dev=/dev/ttyACM0

while using /dev/ttyACMx is a workaround it could also randomly fail due to how Linux "randomly" assigns these paths so that ttyACM0 sometimes becomes ttyACM1.

once this debian fix needs to make it into pi https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1035094
    you can remove the --dev=/dev/ttyACM0 from the deconz startup
```